# Is there any way to turn on/off Num, Caps and Scroll Lock lights?

Tags: java, keyboard, light

Is there any way to turn on/off Num, Caps and Scroll Lock lights? It's just for fun and my idea is to do something like disco.

Comment: What OS?  As far as I know there are only OS-specific ways of doing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK, true);
```

to set Caps lock On.

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK, false);
```

to set Caps lock Off.

and

```
boolean isCapsLockOn = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
```

to get current status.

use `KeyEvent.VK_NUM_LOCK` for num lock.

I have tested this on Windows. I'm not sure about other OSs but I would think it would work.

Comment: just to be clear, this actually changes their states and not just turns the lights on/off, correct?

Comment: @Daniel on my system it does change the state with in-turn turns the light on/off.

Comment: It also changes the states, yes. But that isn't a problem. Here the outcome: http://non.dagrevis.lv/junk/java/Disco.jar . =]

Answer (score 0):

Probably through JNI and a c method. Check some discussions here:

http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=50596#50596

http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8372

Answer (score -1):

I think you cannot set Caps/Scroll lock's lights independently from their own activation, in a direct way.

You could only achieve such behaviour by programming a keyboard driver of your own (or eventually browsing the web for a driver that might already have been developed to achieve such a behavior), but that is not recommended, and goes way beyond the boundaries of java.

Also, this question is a similar duplicate of [Way to turn on keyboard's caps-lock light without actually turning on caps-lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248358/way-to-turn-on-keyboards-caps-lock-light-without-actually-turning-on-caps-lock) , even though in this other question that behavior is intended in C#.

However, the issue, impossibility, and the way around it, are the same.